# How to get list of font styles (wpf)

Tags: wpf, font-family

Where does the fontdialog get its list of fontstyles?

FontStyles consists only of Normal, Oblique and Italic.
Yet, going thru the font styles for the various fonts, there are combinations of: medium, light, demi, bold, roman, narrow, heavy, cond, ... and more.

The fontdialog for Arial shows:

Narrow Italic,
Italic,
Regular,
Narrow Bold,
Narrow Bold Italic,
Bold,
Bold Italic,
Black,
Black Oblique

Where are they getting this list from? Some of those names don't seem to appear anywhere.
Is there some list of FamilyTypeface weight, style and stretch combinations that have other assigned names or something?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 10):

For system-fonts, you can get list of [typefaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.fontfamily.familytypefaces(v=vs.110).aspx) for a `FontFamily`. The typeface itself has all the details for attributes such as weight, style, stretch etc.

### Sample code

```
<Grid Margin="20">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ListBox x:Name="fontSelector" 
             ItemsSource="{x:Static Fonts.SystemFontFamilies}" />

    <ListBox x:Name="typefaceSelector" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.FamilyTypefaces, ElementName=fontSelector}" DisplayMemberPath="AdjustedFaceNames[en-US]" 
             Grid.Column="1" />

    <TextBlock FontFamily="{Binding SelectedItem.Source, ElementName=fontSelector}"
               FontStretch="{Binding SelectedItem.Stretch, ElementName=typefaceSelector}"
               FontStyle="{Binding SelectedItem.Style, ElementName=typefaceSelector}"
               FontWeight="{Binding SelectedItem.Weight, ElementName=typefaceSelector}"
               Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1"
               Text="Sample" 
               FontSize="30"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

[image]

To further expand this list in WPF, you can use `InstalledFontCollection` from win-forms to get the list of installed fonts, and convert them to WPF font type(s).

```
var installedFontCollection = new System.Drawing.Text.InstalledFontCollection();

// Get the array of FontFamily objects.
var fontFamilies = installedFontCollection.Families;
foreach(var fontFamily in fontFamilies)
{
    var mfont = new FontFamily(fontFamily.Name);
    fontSelector.Items.Add(mfont);
}
```

[image]